# Set delay on click event

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I want to load this script after loading the page so I want to set a delay for this code to work -

```
document.getElementsByClassName("pdp-button_theme_bluedaraz")[0].click();
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "delay" you mean a timer and a function which is called after the timer finishes you might want to use `setTimeout()` function. argument 1 is the function to be called and argument 2 is the countdown time in milliseonds eg:

```js
setTimeout(exec, 2000);

function exec() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("pdp-button_theme_bluedaraz")[0].click();
}
```

or if you mean execute the script after page has loaded try this

```js
document.onload = function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("pdp-button_theme_bluedaraz")[0].click();
}
```